# React: mapping out elements inside a conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map out an array within a conditional render. My `li` elements are flashing for a split second and then disappearing.  I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
{ 
  (this.props.rootOb.label == 'type') &&
  <div className="root-name">
    {
      this.state.features.map((feature,index) =>
        <div><li key={index}>hi</li></div>
      )
    }
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I guess it's most probably not error in rendering but in setting the state, I suspect sometime in the lifecycle method, you are resetting the state to empty array

Comment: can you show the whole component?

Comment: Couple of clarification. 1. Check whether you are updating the state in componentDidMount?

Comment: My guess is that when the `li` element disappears, this condition is no longer true `this.props.rootOb.label == 'type'`.

Comment: @CRayen yep, it's being updated in compontentDidMount.  I even have an initialState set for `features` with a dummy array just to try to get something to show

Comment: @TomCoughlin thank you, you were right.  I removed that and it's working. I have to trace back to see where that `label` is no longer `type`

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing `div`. Also its better to list `li`'s within `ul` tag. It should be like below.

```
{this.props.rootOb.label == "type" && (
   <div className="root-name">
      <ul>
          {
            this.state.features.map((feature, index)=>{
                return <li key={index}>hi</li>
            })
          }
      </ul>
   </div>
)}
```

Comment: sorry, that was just a type on my part while writing out my question.  I have the closing tag on the div.  It's still not working.

Comment: map syntax looks wrong. check my updated ans, finally you have to return within the map

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is when you have label but features still null, undefined or empty array, your elements (empty div) gets rendered. And once you get the features, it's rendered and thus you're seeing the flashing. So, be sure to only render when you have features:

```
{ 
  (this.props.rootOb.label == 'type') &&
  this.state.features && this.state.features.length &&
  <div className="root-name">
    {
      this.state.features.map((feature,index) =>
        <div><li key={index}>hi</li></div>
      )
    }
  </div>
}
```

Also, I suspect if you have ul tag in parent? Be sure you have.

Notice: ul tag cannot have div tag directly. You need to use li tag and then you can use div tag inside that.

```
{ 
  (this.props.rootOb.label == 'type') &&
  this.state.features && this.state.features.length &&
  <ul className="root-name">
    {
      this.state.features.map((feature,index) =>
        <li key={index}>hi</li>
      )
    }
  </ul>
}
```